# APK Analyzer diff makes no sense

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I am comparing two APKs to determine why one of them is so much larger than the other.

I am using APK Analyzer, and I think I might have something wrong in my brain, because I cannot make any sense of what I am looking at.

I am posting the following diff in two parts since my monitor isn't large enough to capture the entire list.

If you look at the total (the first line, highlighted in blue), the diff is a substantial 45MB.
But if you carefully look at the contents, this number does not seem to add up. It actually looks like the "larger" apk should be smaller just by glancing at the numbers.

I am sure I am making some sort of stupid mistake or I am just not using this tool correctly.

Thanks for your input.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't get it either. Maybe file a bug with Android Studio.